# How to locate scene over the hud Andengine

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, overlay, andengine, scene, hud

Can anybody help me with some solution or example?
Problem in this:
I have a scene and attached hud, i want to locate scene over the hud.

I think i want to dig at zindex path or what?

Thanks, Sorry for my eng :/

PS.Like a dark overlay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void createHUD() {
        gameHUD = new HUD();

        scoreText = new Text(70, 420, resourcesManager.fontgame,"Score: 0123456789", new TextOptions(HorizontalAlign.LEFT),vbom);
        //scoreText.setColor(android.graphics.Color.rgb(253, 193, 7));
        scoreText.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        scoreText.setAnchorCenter(0, 0);
        scoreText.setText("Score: 0");

        heart1 = new Sprite(760, 460, resourcesManager.heart_region, vbom);
        heart2 = new Sprite(710, 460, resourcesManager.heart_region, vbom);
        heart3 = new Sprite(660, 460, resourcesManager.heart_region, vbom);

        gameHUD.attachChild(scoreText);
        gameHUD.attachChild(heart1);
        gameHUD.attachChild(heart2);
        gameHUD.attachChild(heart3);
        camera.setHUD(gameHUD);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add scene to hud layer which having  any rectangle entity as child. i think it may work.